# Convert specific characters into French letters

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I have a string which is originally in French, but due to some reason some french letters are receiving in this form : =E9 , =EA

Now =E9 was originally this character : é

So how can i convert these characters " =E9 , =EA " into its orignal form like : " é , ó "

**I have this Example PHP string :**

```
Merci beaucoup mais le d=E9m=E9nagement est fait par nos propres moyens. Me=
rci
quand m=EAme



Le 19 octobre 2013 17:00, Support FretBay  a =E9crit
```

**I got the Solution. Here is the ANSWER:**

```
echo quoted_printable_decode($string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This encoding is called **Quoted Printable** and in PHP you might want to look at this https://www.php.net/quoted_printable_decode.

If you want to get a UTF-8 string you can do it as follows:

```
$utf8 = mb_convert_encoding(quoted_printable_decode($input), 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Comment: With your example string it works perfectly: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qIlNw4 Are you sure you have the correct encoding also there where you're printing the string to (console/HTML document)?

Comment: Perhaps you want to skip the UTF-8 conversion part and just use the output of `quoted_printable_decode()`.

Comment: From where can I get all the list of these types of character like " =E9 , =E0" ???

Comment: It is just an hexadecimal conversion. If you are having trouble drop the mb_convert_encoding and use just `quoted_printable_decode($input)`

Comment: Yes its working, but m asking that from where can i get the list of all the characters like this  " =E9 , =E0" ???

Comment: The number after the "=" sign is a hexadecimal ordinal number of the character. Which character it represents depends on the encoding. For French it will usually be ISO-8859-1 and you can find the whole set here - http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm. The numbers you are searching for are in the very right column.